# display abitrary axis values for bokeh figure

Tags: bokeh

Is there a way to arbitrarily specify the values displayed on an axis for a Bokeh figure?

For example, imagine that you have a categorical axis with `x_range` `[Jan 2001, Feb 2001, Mar 2001, ... December 2010]`, but you want to display just the year values `[2001, 2002, ... 2010]`. So an obvious way to do that is to specify a value-to-display mapping where all the January values are mapped to the year string, and all the other values are mapped to an empty string. Is this actually possible in Bokeh?

Comment: This was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use custom labels for ticks in Bokeh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh)