# Categorical axis with a bokeh area chart

Tags: python, bokeh

### Question

Is it currently possible to use a categorical axis with a bokeh `Area` chart?

### Details

I'm trying to plot an area chart with a categorical x-axis using the high-level `bokeh.charts` API.

### Example

If set up bokeh and a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from bokeh import charts, plotting, models
plotting.output_notebook()

_, blue, _, green = bokeh.palettes.Paired4

datalist = [
    {'month': 'Oct', 'rain': 107., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 0},
    {'month': 'Nov', 'rain': 23.6, 'snow': 0.8, 'wy_month': 1},
    {'month': 'Dec', 'rain': 31.9, 'snow': 30.5, 'wy_month': 2},
    {'month': 'Jan', 'rain': 44.6, 'snow': 31.1, 'wy_month': 3},
    {'month': 'Feb', 'rain': 49.6, 'snow': 31.7, 'wy_month': 4},
    {'month': 'Mar', 'rain': 13.6, 'snow': 4.2, 'wy_month': 5},
    {'month': 'Apr', 'rain': 107.2, 'snow': 1.6, 'wy_month': 6},
    {'month': 'May', 'rain': 77.0, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 7},
    {'month': 'Jun', 'rain': 108., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 8},
    {'month': 'Jul', 'rain': 216., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 9},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'rain': 76.8, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 10},
    {'month': 'Sep', 'rain': 76.4, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 11},
]

data = pandas.DataFrame(datalist)
```

I can do:

```
bar = charts.Bar(data=data, values='rain', label='month',
               color=[blue], width=600, height=300)
plotting.show(bar)

scatter = charts.Scatter(data=data, x='month', y='rain',
                         color=[blue], width=600, height=300)
plotting.show(scatter)
```

and I get:

[image: bars]

and

[image: scatter]

### What I've tried

But if I do that same with an area chart:

```
area = charts.Area(data=data, y='rain', x='month', stack=True,
                   color=blue, width=600, height=300)
plotting.show(area)
```

I get:

[image]

### Other efforts

Removing the explicit definition of `x` makes the areas show up, but with a numeric axis (0 - 12).

```
area = charts.Area(data=data, y='rain', stack=True,
                   color=blue, width=600, height=300)
```

Specifying an `x_range` as either a list or `bokeh.models.ranges.FactorRange` seems to have no effect (with and without `x='month'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to make custom tick labels for your axes. Modifying from the answer here - [How do I use custom labels for ticks in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh):

First up we do our imports and create a dictionary to store our modified labels (using Jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy
import pandas
from bokeh import charts, plotting, models
import bokeh
from bokeh.models.formatters import TickFormatter, String, List, Dict, Int
from bokeh.models import FixedTicker
plotting.output_notebook()

_, blue, _, green = ['#a6cee3', '#1f78b4', '#b2df8a', '#33a02c']

datalist = [
    {'month': 'Oct', 'rain': 107., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 0},
    {'month': 'Nov', 'rain': 23.6, 'snow': 0.8, 'wy_month': 1},
    {'month': 'Dec', 'rain': 31.9, 'snow': 30.5, 'wy_month': 2},
    {'month': 'Jan', 'rain': 44.6, 'snow': 31.1, 'wy_month': 3},
    {'month': 'Feb', 'rain': 49.6, 'snow': 31.7, 'wy_month': 4},
    {'month': 'Mar', 'rain': 13.6, 'snow': 4.2, 'wy_month': 5},
    {'month': 'Apr', 'rain': 107.2, 'snow': 1.6, 'wy_month': 6},
    {'month': 'May', 'rain': 77.0, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 7},
    {'month': 'Jun', 'rain': 108., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 8},
    {'month': 'Jul', 'rain': 216., 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 9},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'rain': 76.8, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 10},
    {'month': 'Sep', 'rain': 76.4, 'snow': 0.0, 'wy_month': 11},

]

data = pandas.DataFrame(datalist)
label_data = {x['wy_month']:x['month'] for x in datalist}
```

Now we define our custom label class (and associated JS code):

```
JS_CODE =  """
        _ = require "underscore"
        Model = require "model"
        p = require "core/properties"
        class FixedTickFormatter extends Model
          type: 'FixedTickFormatter'
          doFormat: (ticks) ->
            labels = @get("labels")
            return (labels[tick] ? "" for tick in ticks)
          @define {
            labels: [ p.Any ]
          }
        module.exports =
          Model: FixedTickFormatter
    """

class FixedTickFormatter(TickFormatter):

    labels = Dict(Int, String, help="""
    A mapping of integer ticks values to their labels.
    """)

    __implementation__ = JS_CODE
```

And plot your chart with modified axes:

```
area = charts.Area(data=data, y='rain', x='wy_month', stack=True,
                   color=blue, width=600, height=300)
area.xaxis[0].formatter = FixedTickFormatter(labels=label_data)
area.xaxis[0].ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=sorted(label_data.keys()))
plotting.show(area)
```

Here is the final plot I get:

[image: Bokeh area plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like this will work, but I'll leave the question open a little longer. Also, any thought on how to get all of the months to show up like on the scatter plot?

Comment: No worries. I'll update my answer to include a custom ticker so that you get all the months showing up (and no intermediate ticks between months).