# Python - How to add annotation to my vbar in bokeh?

Tags: python, graph, bokeh

This is the code for the following graph

```
x= np.linspace(0.5, 6, 5)
y= rf[:5]

p_importance =figure()

p_importance.vbar(
    x = x,
    top = y,
    width = 1
)
```

[image]

My list is saved here, how to add the following as a legend

```
 new_labels = list(rf[:5].index)
```

Comment: Can you show what the value of `rf` is?

Comment: @Yserbius it is of type pandas.core.series.Series. and I accessed the contents using .index and .values. I want to use the .index for the legend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in way to do it. You will need to use a custom `TickFormatter` and pass along the labels to it. The following question does it using `FuncTickFormatter`.

[How do I use custom labels for ticks in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh)