# How can i update a figure x_range if it's a stringList?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to change the x axis of a bokeh plot.

```
xrange = ["Marseille", "Lyon"]

plot = figure(x_range=xrange)

plotSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=xrange, y=[1, 2]))

bars = VBar(x="x", top="y", width=0.1, fill_color="black")

plot.add_glyph(plotSource, bars)

handler = show(plot, notebook_handle=True)

plot.x_range = ["Marseille", "Paris"]  # how can i do that

push_notebook(handle=handler)
```

```
ValueError: expected an instance of type Range, got ['Marseille', 'Paris'] of type list
```

I can't create a range from a list, how can i do ?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to change axis ticks values. If so, have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already set the `x_range` in the figure constructor and you are trying to set it twice later on. But then you should use `plot.x_range.factors = ["Marseille", "Paris"]`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, VBar

xrange = ["Marseille", "Lyon"]
plot = figure(x_range = xrange)
plotSource = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = xrange, y = [1, 2]))
bars = VBar(x = "x", top = "y", width = 0.1, fill_color = "black")
plot.add_glyph(plotSource, bars)
handler = show(plot, notebook_handle = True)

plot.x_range.factors = ["Marseille", "Paris"]

show(plot)
```

Or maybe this is a simpler code that you want (using your `source`):

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

xrange = ["Marseille", "Lyon"]
p = figure(x_range = xrange)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = xrange, y = [1, 2]))
bars = p.vbar(x = "x", top = "y", source = source, width = 0.1, fill_color = "black")

show(p)
```