# Is it possible to use commas instead of dots as decimal separators in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, decimal-point

I currently have this code but I was wondering if it's possible to use commas instead of dots to show the decimals.

```py
# Plot
p = figure(title="Weerstand-temperatuurcoefficient",
           x_axis_label="Temperatuur (C)",
           y_axis_label="Weerstand (\u03A9)",
           plot_width=1520,
           plot_height=770
           )

p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.00")
```

Comment: Did you experiment with changing the format string?

Comment: Yeah I tried the format="0,00" but this makes it so that there are no decimals

Comment: It is a good question. It does seem to be a gap in the library. Your best approach might be to not use numerical ticks at all so much as custom strings which are under your full control. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37173230/4996248) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

BokehJS uses JavaScript so by default you will have the dot as decimal separator and as you already checked there is no option in Bokeh formatters for this. However you could use `plot.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {1: "1,0", 2: "2,0"...}` to make your `xaxis` values look as you like.

One approach would be to take over all values from `renderer.data_source.data['x']`, put them on x-axis and then replace them with your "comma-separated" values like this (works for Bokeh v2.1.1):

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FixedTicker

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[1,2,3,4], y=[4,5,5,4]))

plot = figure()
lines = plot.line('x', 'y', source = source)

plot.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[i for i in source.data['x']])
plot.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {i:'{},0'.format(i) for i in source.data['x']}

show(plot)
```

If you need to update the plot dynamically you would need to set a CustomJS callback on the plot's range and update the `xaxis` values accordingly like:

`plot.x_range.js_on_change('end', CustomJS(args={..}, code='...'))`

[image]