# how to add secondary x-axis with my String labels

Tags: python, bokeh

I have plot [image]

with secondary axis added like this:

```
    plot.extra_x_ranges['sec_x_axis'] = Range1d(0, 100)
    ax2 = LinearAxis(x_range_name="sec_x_axis", axis_label="secondary x-axis")
    plot.add_layout(ax2, 'above')
```

x_axis is x_axis_type='datetime', so bokeh show ms on second x-axis too. This is not good. 
Is there a way I can put my labels on this axis? I have a list of str labels like:

```
my_labels = ['21.5; 315.1', '21.6; 315.0', '21.7; 315.0', '21.7; 314.9',.....]
```

I found FuncTickFormatter but it takes JS code inside, so I can't handle it.
Maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use custom labels for ticks in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173230/how-do-i-use-custom-labels-for-ticks-in-bokeh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the values of the labels use `major_label_overrides` on the appropriate axis. You can pass a dictionary like `{1:'A', ...}`, where `1` is the place to overwrite and `A` is the new label.
To avoid "wrong" labels while zooming, you can set the ticker direcetlly as list unsing `ticker`.
In your case the axis is `p.above[0]`.

**Comment**

If you add a LinearAxis to a figure with an already existing DatetimeAxis, the new axis shoudn't be effected and therefor shouldn't be formatted as datetime. I used the latest version 2.4.3 and it works as expected. Use the minimal example to try it on your own.

**Minimal Example**

This code is based on the [twin_axis.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.0/examples/plotting/file/twin_axis.py) example published by the authors of bokeh.

```
from numpy import arange, linspace, pi, sin

from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

x = arange(-2*pi, 2*pi, 0.2)
x2 = arange(-pi, pi, 0.1)
y = sin(x)
y2 = sin(x2)

p = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
    x_range=(-6.5, 6.5),
    y_range=(-1.1, 1.1),
    min_border=80,
    x_axis_type="datetime"
)

p.circle(x, y, color="crimson", size=8)
p.yaxis.axis_label = "red circles"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_color ="crimson"

p.extra_x_ranges['foo'] = Range1d(-pi, pi)
p.circle(x2, y2, color="navy", size=8, x_range_name="foo")
ax2 = LinearAxis(x_range_name="foo", axis_label="blue circles")
ax2.axis_label_text_color ="navy"
p.add_layout(ax2, 'above')

# set ticker to avoid wrong formatted labels while zooming
p.above[0].ticker = list(range(-3,4))
# overwrite labels
p.above[0].major_label_overrides = {key: item for key, item in zip(range(-3,4), list('ABCDEFG'))}

show(p)
```

| **default** | **overwritten labels** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: sinus over time default] | [image: sinus over time] |